# Notify not waking waiting threads

Tags: java, multithreading, quartz-scheduler, synchronized

This is my Class. I am using a Quartz scheduler and in that once a job is toBeExecuted, I wanted to avoid concurrency..hence used Synchronize keyword.. and used wait for each thread but it seems that once job is executed..Notify doesnt call the waiting thread ..please help...stuck on this from last two days:

```
public class SJobListener  implements JobListener {
    public static final String LISTENER_NAME = "SchedulerJobListener";
    ExecutingClass compSched = new ExecutingClass();
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return LISTENER_NAME; //must return a name
    }

    // Run this if job is about to be executed.
    @Override
    public  void jobToBeExecuted(JobExecutionContext context) {

        String jobName = context.getJobDetail().getKey().toString();
        System.out.println("jobToBeExecuted");
        System.out.println("Listener : Job : " + jobName + " is going to start...");
        System.out.println("Thread running in jobToBeExecuted :"+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
        synchronized (compSched) {
            if(!condition)
                try {
                    System.out.println("Going to Wait");
                    Thread.currentThread().wait(200);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }


        }



    }

    //Run this after job has been executed
    @Override
    public  void jobWasExecuted(JobExecutionContext context,
            JobExecutionException jobException) {
        System.out.println("jobWasExecuted");

        String jobName = context.getJobDetail().getKey().toString();
        System.out.println("Listener :Job : " + jobName + " is finished...");
        System.out.println("Thread running in jobWasExecuted :"+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+Thread.currentThread().getId());

        //synchronized (compSched) {
            System.out.println("Notifying waiting threads");
            //context.notifyAll();

            Thread.currentThread().notifyAll();

        if (!jobException.getMessage().equals("")) {
            System.out.println("Exception thrown by: " + jobName
                + " Exception: " + jobException.getMessage());
            jobException.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Out Of jobWasExecuted");
    }


}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You current implementation will throw IllegalStateException please post actual code.

Comment: In theory,it is not a good practice to call wait and notiy on Thread Object.If any thread is calling join,then it may get affected

Comment: possible duplicate of [calling notify is not waking up the other waiting thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20440485/calling-notify-is-not-waking-up-the-other-waiting-thread)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read on java concurrency:

Threads wait on a lock. This lock is what is used to notify other threads waiting on the same lock.

Consider:

```
public class SynchronizedExample{

  private final Object LOCK = new Object();

  public void doSomethingOr() {
    if(somethingIsNotDone()) {
      synchronize(LOCK) {
        LOCK.wait(); //trycatch here
      }
    }
  }

  public void somethingSone() {
   somethingIsDone = true;
   synchronized(LOCK) {
     LOCK.notifyAll(); //trycatch
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `Thread.currentThread().wait(200);` with `compSched.wait(200)`.

And in jobWasExecuted you should call `notify` on `compSched`

Answer (score 0):

The methods jobToBeExecuted and jobWasExecuted are running in different threads so you are waiting on a different object and expecting notifications on a different object. That is why it does not work.

If you explained your requirements a bit more succinctly, a different solution could be provided other than wait notify mechanism.